# Error in qlogis(p) in lme4 with logit family

Tags: r, distribution, lme4

I am trying to fit a GLMM to size (body length) data of fish larvae from different regions at different temperatures. Each region-temperature combination has measurements for at least 10 individuals and up to 30 individuals. The data in question were collected during the first 30 days of life, during which growth is not completely linear. The raw data would look like the bottom half of a logistic (s-shape) curve.

I am using lme4 and the model I am trying to fit, is as follows:

```
length.mod1<-glmer(length~region+treatment+day+region*treatment+
  region*day+treatment*day+region*treatment*day+(1|aquarium)+(1|tub),
  data=lengthdata, family=logit)
```

I also specified factors as follows:

```
region<-factor(lengthdata$region)
day<-factor(lengthdata$day)
treatment<-lengthdata$treatment
length<-lengthdata$length
```

When I run the model, I get the follow error, as follows:

> Error in qlogis(p) : argument "p" is missing, with no default

I have tried Google, this forum, as well as the documentation for lme4, and have not found any reference to this error. I understand it has something to do with the distribution that is specified for the data with the     `family` argument, but I am not sure what exactly.

The data is available here: [length data](http://we.tl/dMqqLhLs2C)

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you happen to have the `boot` package attached by any chance? Or add your `sessionInfo()` to the question.

Comment: Yes, the `boot` package is installed. I just checked session info.

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to the family call. One is the probability distribution of the response (eg. binomial, poisson, ...), and the other is the link function, which relates the response to the linear predictor.

The `family` argument in `glmer()` (like `glm()`) is very flexible. To quote [?glm](http://search.r-project.org/R/library/stats/html/glm.html),

> For glm this can be a character string naming a family function, a
>   family function or the result of a call to a family function.

[?family](http://search.r-project.org/R/library/stats/html/family.html) gives us the valid families and corresponding link functions. So for a binomial family with a logit link function, `binomial(link = logit)`, `binomial(link = 'logit')`, and `'binomial'` are all examples of valid family specifications. The last one is valid because by default, the link function is the *canonical* link, ie. the logit link. In your example, you (I think) meant to specify the link function, but R needs the probability distribution.

The bit of code that checks the family is:

```
if (is.character(family)) 
    family <- get(family, mode = "function", envir = parent.frame(2))
if (is.function(family)) 
    family <- family()
```

The typical error for a misspecified family would be something like:

```
library(lme4)
library(boot)
f1 <- cbind(incidence, size - incidence) ~ period + (1|herd)
m1 <- glmer(f1, data = cbpp, family = 'foo')
##Error in get(family, mode = "function", envir = parent.frame(2)) : 
##  object 'foo' of mode 'function' was not found
```

In your case, `logit` is a function imported by `boot` (and is not a valid family object), and so gets to the fourth line before erroring (because `logit` needs at least one argument, and doesn't get one). One correct family specification would be:

```
m1 <- glmer(f1, data = cbpp, family = binomial(link = 'logit'))
```

Another note: if you are trying to specify interactions in your model, `a*b` is shorthand for `a + b + a:b`, where `a:b` is the interaction term. If I'm reading it right, you only really need the `region*treatment*day`, which will expand to include all simple effects and interactions. The other terms are redundant.

And another note: if your outcome is length, logistic regression might not be entirely appropriate (length didn't make it into your csv though, so I can't tell for sure). Logistic regression implies that the response is bounded between 0 and 1, and the response is the probability of an outcome, eg. like above, the proportion of CBPP cases in a time period. Have you considered nonlinear regression (examples [here](http://www.hafro.is/~arnima/pdf/2013-orange.pdf) and [here](http://rpubs.com/aforren1/orange-nonlinear) for orange tree growth)?

Comment: Hi @alexforrence, I have since realized that mistake and specified `family=poisson(link="logit")`, however I get an error saying Eigenvalue is very large and model is almost unrecognizable. 
The line below that error asks to rescale the variables. I have tried rescaling but the error doesn't go away. Any thoughts?

Comment: Poisson shouldn't accept the logit link (again, see [?family](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/family.html)). You should probably post a new question, as that is a separate issue, but look up the error first. It's difficult to say, as the .csv you uploaded is missing the response.